# Project Reactor - ConnectionProvider.evictInBackground()

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

What is the benefit of using **evictInBackground** operation on **ConnectionProvider** which is used with **HttpClient.create(connectionProvider)**  in springboot webflux ?

Answer (score 3):

By default, the connection pool **timeouts** (**maxIdleTime**, **maxLifeTime** etc.) are checked on connection **release** or **acquire** operations and, if some timeout is reached, the connection is closed and removed from the connection pool. However, you can also configure the connection pool, by setting **evictInBackground**, to perform periodic checks on connections.
The configuration **evictInBackground** is often combined with **disposeInactivePoolsInBackground** to remove from the structures all inactive connection pools.